# Will iOS app made on xcode 10.1 run on iOS version 13 or later?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, macos-high-sierra

I am making an iOS app on xcode 10.1 on MacBook air mid 2011 (macOS high sierra 10.13.6). I have a question that if I deploy this app on App store. Will it also be available for iPhones running iOS 13 or later ? as xcode 10.1 only supports SKDs for iOS 12

Thanks in advance for any kind of guidance in this regard :)

Comment: I would add one point to both very good answers - deprication. For instance, OpenGL, or `GLKit`. While *currently* this is "depricated" as of almost 2 years ago (WWDC 2018) in favor of Metal, there is **no** guarantee that in 4 weeks (WWDC 2020) Apple won't announce that submissions to the App Store at some point will be declined if you use it at some point. I personally expect this to not happen for a few years (maybe more), but who knows? And if you need to target iOS 13 SDK you may well need Catalina, as XCode 11.4 requires it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, apps built with an older SDK will generally run on newer versions of iOS. There are thousands of apps on the App Store that were built before iOS 13 was available and they still run.

Now, the bad news.  After June 30, 2020 all apps submitted to the App Store must be built against the iOS 13 SDK (The original deadline was April 30).

So, in a little over a month you will need to use Xcode 11 to submit new or updated apps.

Comment: what would u suggest me ? what should I do now ?

Comment: Get a newer Mac?  It doesn't have to brand new.  Even a five year old Mac runs Catalina.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, apps made on Xcode 10.1 will work on IOS version 13 or later

However, There is a deadline on June 30th 2020 to submit app made through Xcode 11.

In few month, all apps must be made with Xcode 11 to be submitted to the app store.

Comment: what would u suggest me ? what should I do now ?

Comment: Do you have any apps on the AppStore? If you do, I recommend submitting it because I have heard they may remove your binary(app) from the AppStore.

Comment: Not yet.. this is first one I am making... I am gonna grab new mac which supports xcode with iOS 13 SDK. That is the only option i am left with ig :/